# Show Progress Android Login

Tags: java, android, authentication

Please have read so many on this,(it says i should not put the dialog in the doInbackground) But have been trying to get this done for a while,Its actually my first android app(with java). Please how do i show the loading bar,disable button (till there's response) and redirect to another activity on success.

```
public class Index extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  EditText username, password; 
    Button login;
    String uname,pass;
    TextView login_err; 

    HttpClient httpclient;

    HttpPost   htpost;

    ArrayList <NameValuePair> namearray;

    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;
    int Server_response;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
        login_err= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_err);
        initialise();

    }



    private void initialise() {
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login= (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);;
    }

    public void onClick(View v)  {
       String umail=username.getText().toString();
       String pass= password.getText().toString();
       if(umail.length()!=0 && pass.length()!=0){
           new MyAsyncTask().execute();
       }else{
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please provide username and password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }


    }//END onClick()

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }//END convertStreamToString()



    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if(Server_response==1){
               mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Index.this, "Loading...", "Logging In...");
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //Create new default HTTPClient
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //Create new HTTP POST with URL to php file as parameter
           htpost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/fanaticmobile/log_in.php"); 

            //Assign input text to strings
            uname= username.getText().toString();
            pass= password.getText().toString();



            //Next block of code needs to be surrounded by try/catch block for it to work
            try {
                //Create new Array List
               namearray = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                //place them in an array list
               namearray.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
               namearray.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));

                //Add array list to http post
                htpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namearray));


                //assign executed form container to response
                response= httpclient.execute(htpost); //response from the PHP file

                //check status code, need to check status code 200
                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){


                    //assign response entity to http entity
                    entity= response.getEntity();

                    //check if entity is not null
                    if(entity != null){


                        //Create new input stream with received data assigned
                        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                        //Create new JSON Object. assign converted data as parameter.
                        JSONObject jresponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                        //assign json responses to local strings
                        String logged= jresponse.getString("logged");
                         if(logged.equals("true")){
                            Server_response=1;
                            //Please i want to redirect to a new activity here
                         }else{
                             Log.d("Error Invalid credentials",logged);
                             Server_response=0;
                         }


                    }


                }


            } catch(Exception e){
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               return null;
            }



            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the loginActivity class from the android sdk there's a template that do what you want.

They have a method that shows an animation while the asynctask is running, you just have to call it before executing your asynctask like that

```
showProgress(true);
mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();            
mAuthTask.execute();
```

here's the method:

```
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE
                                : View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and then in your asynctask you use onPostExecute which will be called after the asynctask is completed and you can stop the login animation and launch a new activity from there

```
protected void onPostExecute(String[] userDetails) {
showProgress(false);
```

}

Comment: Thanks alot,I'd look at the function you mentioned. Really appreciate.

Comment: You'r welcome, also check the xml file of loginActivity so you will have the full thing